# "true" 'first' 'last' classes in menus

Tags: theming

I am building a zen subtheme in which I try to adjust my menus from:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first">
        <ul class="menu>
            <li class="first"></li>
            ...
            <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="..."> </li>
    <li class="..."> </li>
    <li class="last">
        <ul class="menu>
            <li class="first"></li>
            ...
            <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

too:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"> <----- mark the very first
        <ul class="menu>
            <li class="..."></li>
            ...
            <li class="..."></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="..."> </li>
    <li class="..."> </li>
    <li class="...">
        <ul class="menu>
            <li class="..."></li>
            ...
            <li class="last"></li> <----- mark the very last li element
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

another example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"> <----- mark the very first
        <ul class="menu>
            <li class="..."></li>
            ...
            <li class="..."></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="..."> </li>
    <li class="..."> </li>
    <li class="last">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know I can handle each menu item with `theme_preprocess_menu_link` but I didn't find a solution to have the very first and last item marked as I need to? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask why you need it? You should be able to use css to single out the two items you are interested just using the classes that are provided out of the box.

Comment: well, everything begun with a simple menu witch should have rounded borders with css only. First I thought, well easy task, no problem. But then my client came up (later on...) with a nice addition to the menu: it will be or has to be as generic as possible, since he does not know how many levels of nested subentries will be needed... Now I "solved" my problem by hardcoding all possibilities till level 3 or so (really messy) and I wanted to find a "good" solution as it is only a simple problem of counting menu elements and its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see added sample image; is this similar to what you want?

[image: Sample for list item CSS]

If so, I achieved it with this CSS code:

```
li:first-child {
color: red;
}

li:first-child li {
color: black;
}

li:last-child li:first-child {
color: yellow;
}

li:last-child li {
color: black;
}

li:last-child li:last-child {
color: green;
}
```

Comment: thx. it appears to be the best approach to hardcode the needed menu depth with css. what I wanted to achieve is an more generic solution because the solution you suggested above is no specifically design to work only with this menu structure (eg. what happens if an 2 level menu is not at the bottom position parent menu.) Anyway thanks for your answer, I will mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that i fully understood what you want; but if what you need is to give special attributes(ID, class etc.) to menu items, [Menu attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module may help. You also could use CSS3 :nth-child() selector.

Comment: the main problem is that each menu element knows whether it has a child/children menu items or not, but **it does not know if there are other menu items on the same level**... **hence the nth-child() will not work**.